# Something went wrong . 33.0.0 is not a valid SDK version . Options are 35.0.0 , 36.0.0 , 38.0.0 ,37.0.0

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am currently using expo - 3.26.2 , react-native - 0.59.10 I have also changed my expo sdk from 38.0.10 to 33.0.0 by changing in package.json doing npm install . Please help

Comment: So what happens if you specify one of the valid Expo SDK versions?

Comment: this is old project I want this to be run in 33.0.0 only with react-native 0.59.10

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your expo version. Try the following steps. Let me know if this doesn't work

```
npm install (for node module)
expo update
npm install react-native-gesture-handler --save
npm start
```

Comment: this is old project I want this to be run in 33.0.0 only with react-native 0.59.10